Not recognizing the data structure that stores the computed MST
I am using the code for computing the Minimal Spanning Tree of a graph (https://github.com/stanojevic/Fast-MST-Algorithm).  The Python code outputs the MST in the form of an array of integers, e.g.: array([-1,  2,  0,  4,  0]).
The API for the main function reads:
# weights[head][dep] =  weight of head ---> dep (head entering dep),
so "dep (head entering dep)" is probably an indication of the data format in which the MST is output.  But, for the life of me, I cannot figure out what it is.  Probably something trivial, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

It should map each vertex to its in-neighbor in the tree. The vertex with in-neighbor -1 is the root.

@JohnKemeny, thanks very much.  Your comment, I believe, deserves to be an answer.

Got an answer from the author of the code: the array is "dependency word."
array[ k ] = m
means that an edge goes from node m to node k.
